# Image doesn't stay inside border/canvas on drag/zoom

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application with Canvas,border and Image.

```
<Canvas Height="300" Width="400" Background="Gray" Margin="10,210,15,150" Grid.Row="1">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Width="400" Height="250" Name="bord" />
    <Image Name="x" Stretch="Fill" MouseWheel="x_MouseWheel" Width="359" Height="230"  Grid.Row="1" Opacity="1" MouseLeftButtonDown="x_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="x_MouseMove" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseLeftButtonUp="x_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="/ProjectOwn;component/Images/First.png"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

The problem is the following: I can drag the image and zoom in or out, but it doesn't stay inside my border/canvas, so i can move it over the whole interface while mouse clicked on it which is not good (the picture over sized also if i zoom out and it takes the whole wpf window). How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want children of `Canvas` to draw beyond its region then you need to set [`ClipToBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds(v=vs.110).aspx) to true

```xml
<Canvas ... ClipToBounds="True">
```